# Logstash aggregate filter: start event but no stop event

Tags: logstash, aggregate, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have log messages which I want to aggregate looking somthing like this:

I left out everything non essential to the question (such as a common ID in all messages)

> Start 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> Start a
>
> b
>
> c

I want to aggregate all messages between to starts --> Start 1 2 3 and Start a b c

The [aggregate filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate) states that when there is no end event, timeouts should be used. My problem is that a timeout is not enough because Start 1 and Start a might happen almost simultaniously and will therefore be aggregated to --> start123abc.

Is there a way to "close" a previous aggregation when a new message begins with start?

Comment: In this combination I don't see how you would do that. You could either separate the first value from the 'start' string and use 'start' as an end event. Don't know how that would work. The other option is that you add an event counter and use the 4# case and aggregate by that. Not sure if these options are useful, just brainstorming here.

Comment: Thats already very helpfull. 
I noticed that there are map update and map create. I'm trying now to have map create on start, map update on others and use a timeout to close it (The messages are generated almost simultaniously so timeouts are no problem).
Each start message will create a new map and I hope that the old one will time out

Comment: If you have something to use as a task_id (as described in the doc), it won't combine them and timeout will work as expected.